# How do you insert your own graphics in Java 7

Tags: java, image, graphics, graphics2d

I am working on a game but I want to put my own graphics into Java. I am using Eclipse and Java 7.
I was wondering of a library that can take care of that and help you use your own graphics.

Edit: What my goal is, is to draw an image, then put in into the program as an object.

Comment: What makes your own graphics different from other graphics?

Comment: Take a look at the Java Tutorial about [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Comment: I want to be able to make custom graphics, and not draw shapes from methods that come with libraries.

Comment: 2D Graphics includes image handling.

Comment: You may be interested in the `Image` class. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) for a tutorial.

Comment: For example, draw the graphics in another program such as paint.NET and then add them into the program

Comment: @user1946564 perhaps your question is about custom shapes rather than custom graphics?

Comment: All I want is to be able to draw in external programs, then use a library to insert the picture/drawing into the program.

Comment: Java is not a Image editing software, instead it is a programming language. So you do not *insert graphic* instead you paint the graphic. See ***[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)*** for a starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking and manipulating existing images can be done with the Java `Image` class.

First, declare an instance of the class (`BufferedImage` is a subclass of `Image`):

```
private BufferedImage img = null;
```

Then, you load the image like this:

```
try
{
    img = ImageIO.read( new File("MyPicture.jpg" ));
}
catch ( IOException exc )
{
    //TODO: Handle exception.
}
```

Finally, in the `paint(Graphics)` method of your code, you display the image like this:

```
g.drawImage( img, x, y, this );
```

Don't forget to write some code to handle the Exception. These things help you find and solve bugs more easily.

The official tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html).